# Are stalks of q-singular cochain equal to 0?($q>0$)

Tags: algebraic-topology, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $\mathcal{S}^{q}$ be the presheaf of singular q-cochains on a topological space $X$, that is the functor $\mathcal{S}^{q} \colon \mathcal{O}(X)^{op} \to \mathbb{Z}$-$\mathsf{Mod}$ which is given by $\mathcal{S}^{q}(U)= \operatorname{Hom}(S_{q}(U), \mathbb{Z})$, where $S_q(U)$ is the abelian group of singular $q$-chains on $X$.
I understood from [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4273609/how-to-check-singular-cochains-are-not-sheaves) why $\mathcal{S}^q$ is not a sheaf but a presheaf.

Now if I take an arbitrary singular chain $\sigma \colon \Delta^q \to X$, the image $\sigma(\Delta^q)$ lies in some open set $W \subset X.$Is the germ of a cochain $f \in \mathcal{S}^q(W)$ satisfying $\langle f, \sigma \rangle =1$ equal to $0$ at any point $x \in W$? I feel if it is true, all of the germs of the presheaves of singular cochains must be $0$ except for the following example as we can chose an open covering $\{U, V \}$ such that $W \not \subset U$ and, $W \not \subset V$.

I found a example of non-zero germ of singular cochain $f \in \mathcal{S}^q(W)$ at $x \in W$ satisfying $\langle f, \sigma \rangle=1$ which image $\sigma(\Delta^q)$ is equal to a point $x \in X$. I'm still confused that the element of sections of the sheafication of the presheaf $\mathcal{S}^q$ are consisted only such elements?

Comment: I've made a few edits which I hope will make your question clearer and easier to read.

Comment: The biggest problem here is: when you say "the stalk of a cochain", you need to specify a point of $X$! There is a different stalk at every point.

Also, the correct word here is "germ", not "stalk". Each section of a presheaf (e.g. $\sigma$) has a germ at each point, and the collection of all germs of sections at a single point is called the stalk of the presheaf at that point.

Comment: I have replaced some words stalk to germ as you mentioned and edited my question.

Comment: What are you asking exactly? Are you asking if you have some cochain $f \in S^q(W)$ so that $f(\sigma) = 1$ there exists a point $x \in W$ so that the germ of $f$ at $x$ equals $0$? The answer to that question can be both yes and no, it depends on what $f$ is.

Comment: If $f \in \mathcal{S}^q(W)$ is non-zero element as a germ for each $x \in W$, then $f(\sigma_{x})=1$ if and only if the image of$\sigma_{x}$ is $x$. Is this true?